# Cumulative Rainfall with GPM between dates

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping, precipitation

I am trying to generate a cumulative rainfall map between two dates using the GSMaP satellite.
I don't know how to do the simple sum of the information in that band "hourlyPrecipRate".

Anyway, if someone comes up with another simpler idea or way to generate the same product, it is also welcome

Code im using

```
var lluvia = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/operational').filterBounds(Uy)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-09-01', '2020-09-15'));
print(lluvia.size());
var precipitation = lluvia.select('hourlyPrecipRate');
var precipitationVis = {min: 0.0, max: 30.0, palette:
      ['1621a2', 'ffffff', '03ffff', '13ff03', 'efff00', 'ffb103', 'ff2300'],};
Map.addLayer(precipitation, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could accumulate all images in the filtered collection using `sum()`:

```
var cumPrec = precipitation.sum();
Map.addLayer(cumPrec, precipitationVis, 'cum Prec');
```